# Goutte Scraping - JSON-LD - Only "@type":"Product"

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, goutte

I use Goutte to **scrape** JSON-LD data, like this:

```
$client = new Client();
$url = "https://www.xxxx.com";
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
$crawler->filterXPath('//*[@type="application/ld+json"]')
      ->each(function ($node) {
          //do something
      }
```

Is it possible to filter such that it is only `"@type": "product"`,
which gets run.

Thanks!